# Importing Firebase database with changed to certain nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to export the Firebase database and then make changes on an editor like Notepad and then import the database enforcing that only the changes made offline get updated?

For example, say I export the database today and add 6000 new child nodes through my notepad and then two days I import the database back to update it with the new nodes without affecting the other updates that have been made by my users.

What happens by default is that when I import the database it will rewrite every value that does not match. Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Export JSON` option from your `Firebase Console`, and than you make some offline changes on that file and than you use `Import JSON` option, no, it's not possible, because the new added file overrides the old one. So in other words, if you previously have made some changes, all the changes will be lost when you upload the modified file.

There are two options to solve this.

> 1. Stop to database for beeing written -> Export the file -> Make the changes -> Import the file.

and

> 2. Make all changes programmatically even if the database is changed by users.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex, i was afraid of those options you suggested because man, that's a lot of work.:'( But thanks again

Comment: You're welcome spongyboss! Unfortunately that's the way `Export/Import JSON` is working for the moment. So, if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see from above image, firebase clearly says **All data at this location will be overwritten**, so you have to stop writing new data when you are updating the data by export and then import.

Now to recover such data, you can code that way to write upcoming data into json file or another database and stop writing it into firebase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Binary, I guess ill have to add those records directly on the server :'(